# Can you drive in Oregon, USA using Texas, USA Learner's Permit?

Tags: usa, driving, driving-licenses, permits

For an adult (age 24yrs), is it legal to drive using learner's permit from TX in OR state?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do USA States have reciprocal agreements for learner drivers' permits?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/31062/do-usa-states-have-reciprocal-agreements-for-learner-drivers-permits), though the link in the accepted answer there is currently dead.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert clever new user [shoover](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/47309/shoover) was able to fix the link.